# How to replace the folder of my url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read a lot of answers here about changing the site language with jQuery but nothing worked for me.

Well, I have a website as an example: **www.domain.com**
Inside I have folders for the languages. **/en/** English pages, **/el/** Greek pages.
All pages are the same, both for English and Greek. *index.html, gallery.html* etc

I have two flag icons in the top right header page to change the language.
I want, when the user clicks the British flag, to go to `/en/page.html` and when the user clicks the Greek flag to go to `/el/page.html`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click(function() {
            document.location.href =document.location.href.replace('/el/' '/en/');
      });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my html code:

```
<head>
<a href="javascript:;"><img src="../images/flagen.gif"></a>
</head>
```

In this example I am on Greek page *rootwww/el/index.html*
and I want to replace /el/ with /en/ folder path and go to 
*/en/index.html*

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's a comma missing from your replace method. Change it to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click(function() {
            document.location.href = document.location.href.replace('/el/','/en/');
      });
    });
</script>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that comma was important for replace method.

Comment: Indeed it is. The syntax is `string.replace(searchval,replaceval)`. You can also use regular expressions for searching. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp for examples.

Comment: BTW, It's not that comma is 'important for the replace method', a comma is important to separate the parameters in a method call, and replace method takes two parameters, what is to be replaced and the new value. So those two should be separated by a comma, as those two are parameters to the replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the comma in the "replace" or is this normal for you?
And you do not need to write twice "document.location.href ...."

I suggest the following code to test

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click(function() {
            var str = document.getElementById('a').document.location.href;
            var newPath= str.replace("/el/","/en/");
            document.location.href =newPath;
      });
    });
```